# Shell script for wallpaper with average for background color

Tags: bash, imagemagick, zsh, wallpaper

Awhile ago I wrote a script for automatically changing wallpapers for my multimonitor setup. I wanted to change it so that the color that fills the extra space is an average of the images, but it just seems to kill the script when I try. Here's what I've got:

```
#!/bin/sh

BACKGROUND="-background #452036"
GRAVITY="-gravity Center"
GRAVITY2="-gravity North"
GRAVITY3="-gravity South"
LEFT_SIZE=1920x1062
RIGHT_SIZE=1280x958
FINAL_SIZE=3200x1080

RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)
FILES=($1/*)
NUM_FILES=${#FILES[*]}
LEFT_IMAGE=${FILES[$RANDOM % $NUM_FILES]}
RIGHT_IMAGE=${FILES[$RANDOM % $NUM_FILES]}

LCOLOR=${convert $LEFT_IMAGE -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" "}
RCOLOR=${convert $RIGHT_IMAGE -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" "}
LBACKGROUND="-background" $LCOLOR
RBACKGROUND="-background" $RCOLOR


convert $LBACKGROUND $GRAVITY -scale $LEFT_SIZE ${LEFT_IMAGE}\
    -extent $LEFT_SIZE ~/.left.png

convert $RBACKGROUND $GRAVITY -scale $RIGHT_SIZE ${RIGHT_IMAGE}\
    -extent $RIGHT_SIZE ~/.right.png

convert $BACKGROUND $GRAVITY2 +append \
~/.left.png \
~/.right.png \
~/.wpcompo.png

convert $BACKGROUND $GRAVITY3 -extent $FINAL_SIZE ~/.wpcompo.png ~/.wallpaper.png
```

It returns:

```
/home/ryan/Scripts/wpconvert.sh: line 17: ${convert ${LEFT_IMAGE} -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" "}: bad substitution
```

Comment: One note about `RANDOM=…`: in bash and zsh `$RANDOM` is a special variable that can’t be set and evaluates to random number (i.e. you will never get the value of `$$$(date +%s)` there, but you will get random integer value). In pure POSIX shell (like dash) there are no arrays (`FILES=($1/*)`) hence there is no need in defining RANDOM: where it is absent script does not work. Due to the mentioned problem you **must not** use `/bin/sh` in shebang, it should be `/bin/bash` there or the script will break on the system where shell used for `/bin/sh` does not have non-POSIX extensions.

Comment: @ZyX Thank you for mentioning this. I've changed it to `/bin/bash` in the script, but also I am just using the standard `$RANDOM` now. `$$$(date +%s)` was suggested by a friend when I first wrote the script as I didn't know about `$RANDOM` at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to run *convert* in a subshell, so you need `$()` instead of `${}`:

```
LCOLOR=$(convert $LEFT_IMAGE -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" ")
RCOLOR=$(convert $RIGHT_IMAGE -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Lines 17 and 18: use

```
LCOLOR=$(convert $LEFT_IMAGE -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" ")
RCOLOR=$(convert $RIGHT_IMAGE -resize 1x1\! -depth 8 txt:- | tail -1 | grep -E -o "#(.)* " | cut -f1 -d" ")
```

instead. You really should use more quotes! your script will fail if some file names contain spaces